# Evaluate mathematical expression in reverse Polish notation in C

Tags: beginner, c, math-expression-eval

This is a program exercise from The C Programming Language by Kernighan and Ritchie (Chap 5).

It is based on my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57919729/why-character-is-not-working-for-multiplication-in-this-rpn-calculator) on Stack Overflow.

One user suggested to submit my code here, saying there's a whole
lot of bad coding practice in this snippet. Since most of the harmful
practice here originates from K&R, you might want to consider a better
source for learning C.

What are instances of bad coding practice in this program? How can it be improved or written in more compact form?

If *The C Programming Language by Kernighan & Ritchie* is not good way to start learning C programming, I'm open to suggestions on an alternative good read.

```
//Exercise 5-10. Write the program expr, which evaluates a reverse Polish
//expression from the command line, where each operator or operand is a
//separate argument. For example, expr 2 3 4 + *
//evaluates 2 x C+4).

//For multiplication character '*' is not working

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
#define NUMBER 0

int sign = 1;
char s[MAXLINE];

void calc (int type);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    if (argc < 4)
        printf("Usage: ./<programName> op1 op2 operator\n");
    else 
    {
        int i, d;
        int c;

        while (--argc > 0 && (c = **++argv) != '\n')
        {   
            i = 0;
            if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '=' || c == '\n')
            {
                if ((c == '+' || c == '-') && isdigit(d = *++(argv[0])))
                {   
                    sign = (c == '-') ? -1 : 1;
                    c = d;
                    goto DOWN1;
                }
                else
                {   
                    calc(c);
                    goto DOWN2; //To avoid re-executing calc(Number) which
                                //is outside any loop in main when operator
                                //is read and operation is performed.
                }   
            }

DOWN1:      while (isdigit(c = *argv[0]))
            {
                s[i++] = c;
                c = *++(argv[0]);

                if (**argv == '.')
                {
                    s[i++] =  **argv;
                    while (isdigit(*++(argv[0])))
                        s[i++] = **argv;
                }
                s[i] = '\0';
            }
            calc(NUMBER);   //Outside while to get single push of s[]
                            //after reading the complete number
DOWN2:      ;
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}

void push (double f);
double pop(void);

void calc (int type)
{
    double op2, res;
    switch(type)
    {
        case NUMBER:
            push(sign*atof(s));
            sign = 1;
            break;
        case '+':
            push(pop() + pop());
            break;
        case '-':
            op2 = pop();
            push(pop() - op2);
            break;
        case '*':
            push(pop() * pop());
            break;
        case '/':
            op2 = pop();
            push(pop() / op2);
            break;
        case '=':
            res = pop();
            push(res);
            printf("\t\t\t||Result = %lg||\n", res);
            break;
        case '\n':
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nError: Invalid Operator!\n");
            break;
    }
}

#define STACKSIZE 1000
double val[STACKSIZE];
int sp = 0;

void push(double f)
{
    if (sp >= STACKSIZE)
        printf("\nError: Stack Overflow!\n");
    else
        val[sp++] = f;
}

double pop(void)
{
    if (sp != 0)
    {
        double ret = val[--sp];
        return ret;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nError: Stack Empty!\n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I polished your question a little bit, but that's not something you should expect for further questions. Taking the [tour] and reading [ask] can help you to improve the quality of your posts.

Comment: Does your code work if `*` is properly escaped? If not, you misunderstood. The referral said: "Once you got everything up and running". If you haven't, we can't review code that not yet works as expected. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AlexV Thanks.. I will go through it and improve the quality of my posts in future..

Comment: @Mast Yes my code works properly if * is properly escaped.. e.g. ./ProgE5-11 +124 -3 '*' = gives -372 which is a correct answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Early returns are OK.

  ```
  if (args < 4) {
      printf(....);
      return;
  }
  ....
  ```

  emphasizes where the business logic is.
- The condition `(c = **++argv) != '\n'` looks sort of strange. It is indeed possible to embed a newline in an argument, but it doesn't warrant a special case. It is just one way to malform an argument, and there are plenty of them.
- `c = d;` does nothing. The very first statement after `goto DOWN1` overrides `c`.
- Avoid `goto`s. I don't see the compelling reason to have them here. Just move the code under `DOWN1` label to where it belongs, and see the `goto`s disappearing. Better yet, factor it out into a function.
- There is no reason to copy the rest of the argument into `s`. You may directly pass it to `atof`. I understand the desire to sanitize the argument, but the way you do it is incorrect. It allows multiple dots, and misinterprets some well-formed floats (those with exponents, like `1e2`). Let `atof` do its job correctly. Better yet, use `strtod`, and check where it stopped parsing.
- Avoid globals. The bullet above eliminates `s`. To eliminate global `sign`, don't cramp everything to `calc`. Just compute the number, and push it. Let `calc` only deal with operators.
- All error messages should go to `stderr`.

Comment: Since I am reading the next character after sign (+ or -) to check whether read +/- is sign or operand (if +/- is succeeded by number then it is interpreted as Sign otherwise as Operand for Addition/Subtraction). Since the 1st digit of number is already read and the program is not using getch() or ungetch() to push the extra character to i/p buffer I saved the next char in 'd' and after evaluating value for' sign', the value in 'd' is restored in 'c' as 'c' used for further calculation.

Comment: Thanks.. I will the improvements you suggested. First I need to understand some of those. But I will read about it and make the changes.